# Generic link to open latest version of document wiki pages

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2007, wiki

Hi I am completely new to Sharepoint and wiki pages. I manage to do few changes to wiki pages to have a feel of it. I noticed that every time i create a link to a document if the version changes i need to update the link manually by editing it. Is there any way to automate this process?

Eg: Docv1.0.doc is updated to Docv2.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you change a document, you don't need to change the file name. SharePoint has versioning built in, so you can keep the file name the same.
That's the only solution actually, don't change the filename. Enable versioning on the library to be able to see previous versions.

Comment: These files are on a shared server

Comment: So, these files are outside SharePoint? And you need to update the links in SharePoint to external files whenever that external link changes? That's impossible without custom code, how can SP know what the new link has to be?

Comment: I am trying to use javascript using webpart content editor. Not very much convinced as this is only way forward. BTW I am using SP 2007

Comment: Sorry I really don't know what you are doing with the javascript, what the links are exactly linking to, how the files get changed on the shared server. So, please elaborate if you want a proper answer...

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint site has several links to templates and documents that points to a shared server and these documents can be updated as new versions, so the links to this files needs to be updated automatically, in fact these links need to call some script for dynamically linking them to the latest files. (not sure if a better way of doing this without a script). Here is what I could manage to do, a better and other options to achieve will be appreciated.

I manage to get something working using webparts Content Editor and linking it to a file. Not sure if this the only/best approached for Sharepoint 2007

```
<script type="text/javascript">


 function getLatestFile(){
      var myObject;
      var recent = "";
      myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
      var folderObj = myObject.GetFolder("C:\Test");
      var fc = new   Enumerator(folderObj.files);

      for(var objEnum = new Enumerator(FileCollection); !objEnum.atEnd(); objEnum.moveNext()) {
       If (recentFile = ""){
           recentFile = file;
      else if (file.DateLastModified > recentFile.DateLastModified){
           recentFile = file;
        }
      }

    }//for loop
    alert("recentFile : " + recentFile);
    var mylink = document.getElementById("myLink");  
    mylink.setAttribute("href", urlToFile);
    mylink.click();   
  }

</script>

<P>&nbsp;</P><A id="myLink" onclick="getUrl();"> TestFile1 </A>
```

[Content Type Editor](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/adding-script-into-a-content-editor-web-part-cewp-in-sharepoint-2007.aspx)

check above link for more on using content links to use JavaScript and HTML.